# SQL Server connection is not establishing connection online in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, connection

I am working on an ASP.NET project. My database is SQL Server.

When I run the project against my local server, the connection is established. But as I put my project on GoDaddy Server and when I try to login, I found that no connection to SQL Server can be established. I am not able to login.

In both cases, I am working with an online database on GoDaddy.

Please help - is there some setting that has to be done on my hosting server?

Comment: Have you updated your connection string in web.config? Please post your connection strings (with any confidential information suitable hidden).

Comment: Check your connection string again. Ask their support team about the connection string that you need to use.

Comment: <add name="artifactEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ArtifactModel.csdl|res://*/ArtifactModel.ssdl|res://*/ArtifactModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=**********;initial catalog=artifact;user id=artifactuser;password=************;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>


this is my connection string...
I am getting this error: - "The provider did not return a ProviderManifest instance."

I have already this- ProviderManifestToken="2008"